# PHP Memcache Extension Incomplete on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, php

The issue is this. I have several servers all running the php5-memcache extension on Ubuntu 12.04. The PHP documentation (on php.net) has several functions like cas that are not part of the default php5-extension on 12.04. The class doe have get, put, add, delete and I think extendedStats or something like that. While I haven't tried every other method of the class listed at php.net all of the other methods I have tried fail.

I assume this is because Ubuntu is using an old or modified version of the memcache class for 12.04.

So how do I fix that? Does anyone know if this is "fixed" in 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly common issue in my experience, you actually want `php5-memcached` (note the d on the end). This should install it and remove the confusingly awful `php5-memcache`:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-memcached php5-memcache-
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing this out now. It appears to have installed something because my old code for set is already broken with a warning about too many input args.

Comment: This worked pretty well for me. However the default version that Ubuntu installed is 1.4.13 and I need some way of getting all of the keys. Memcache offers extended stats and the keys can be extracted from this. But Memcached does not appear to offer anything for this until 2.0.0 - the getAllKeys() method. Any suggestions?

Comment: Store an array of keys at the same time?

Comment: A list of the keys isn't viable in my use case. I'm trying to get data refreshed from a site on the order of 0.1 sec but the API returns in 1-2 sec. So I have a few data pulling scripts running lots of concurrent instances. Each instance dumps it's info into a unique key to avoid write collisions. Then my PHP cache class scans all keys matching a search string and returns the most recently updated one. So the short version is storing the keys in the cache would cause write collisions (I think) and managing a text file with keys has been too slow. CAS may solve the issue though - still testing.

Comment: 14.04 has 2.1, as does the [php5 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5). They're both drastic options but they're both maintained ([Ondřej Surý](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej) does a great job looking after that PPA).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of 14.04 soon anyway. The 12.04 version of Ruby is ridiculously old - 1.8.7. So you have to install rvm to get around it. I'm just waiting for some little config issue to bite me on that one. I think the Ruby in 14.04 is 1.9.? and I'm currently using 2.1.1 so I haven't really decided if 14.04 is the way to go on a new server where I can test all of these things.

Comment: Passed and worked for me with PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 (cli) :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install PHP Memcache Extension and configure it.

```
sudo apt-get install memcached php-pear build-essential
```

After that, run `sudo pecl install memcache` to install memcache

Once you have completed the installation of memcache with PECL, add memcached to memcache.ini:

```
echo "extension=memcache.so" | sudo tee /etc/php5/conf.d/memcache.ini
```

Finally reload apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

And now you're ready to start using memcache.

Comment: I had done all of this except with php-memcache instead of php-memcached. Thanks